# Check app name availability in ios and android

Tags: android, ios

I want to build new app in iOS and android.

I have found this

**iOS**:
To check app availability on iOS we need to create app with the same name and check name is available or not. Can i reserve it?

**android** : package name should be unique. Will it allow same app name for multiple apps?

What's best way to check that app name is available or not in iOS and android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.`package name should be unique.` yes package name should be unique

2.`Will it allow same app name for multiple apps?`  yes you can use same name.

Not sure about IOS

Answer (score 1):

For Android, application name doesn't have to be unique.

To check existing names, do the search Google Play with the exact application name. As application name is very important for search results, this will show all applications with that name at or near the top.

Keep in mind that applications can have different names in different languages.

Comment: Don't know about iOS, I only develop for Android.

Comment: Actually, it may be better for you to ask 2 separate questions, one for iOS and one for Android.